# Is it possible to use a try/catch and not have firebug register it when it catches an exception

Tags: javascript

The false alarms are getting in the way of testing.

I only have one, it is to check if a string is in JSON format or not

```
try{
    return JSON.parse(item);
}catch(e){
    return item;
}
```

So an alternative solution would be a way to test for JSON without try/catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so here some code stolen from jquery src

and they clame to have stolen it from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

```
function isJson(json) {
 var rvalidchars = /^[\],:{}\s]*$/;
 var rvalidescape = /\\(?:["\\\/bfnrt]|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})/g;
 var rvalidtokens = /"[^"\\\n\r]*"|true|false|null|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/g;
 var rvalidbraces = /(?:^|:|,)(?:\s*\[)+/g;

 return rvalidchars.test( 
        json.replace( rvalidescape, "@" )
            .replace( rvalidtokens, "]" )
    .replace( rvalidbraces, ""));
}
```

i hope this helps you :D